# "I'll show it (on? by? with?...) a simple example."

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose, I have conjectured some general law ("The longer the tail is, the cleverer is the owner", say). How to express the idea that I am going to confirm this law by considering a simple specific case (cats, say)?

Comment: "I'll show it with a simple example," or (more formally) "I'll show it by means of a simple example."

Comment: A minor correction: it sounds more fluent to say "The longer the tail is, the cleverer the owner is" so the structure is parallel in both parts of the sentence.